# Schema backup in oracle

Tags: oracle, permissions, backup

While taking backup of a schema, will it also copies the permissions granted on a table in that schema?

Consider a schema `sch_1` and this schema has a table `test_table` which has read access granted to an user `tst_usr`. So, if i take a backup of `sch_1` will it copy the schema along with the access granted to `tst_user` on `test_table`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use full [export](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/exp_imp.htm) or [export data pump](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_export.htm) to get schema.

export:

```
ROWS=N
GRANTS=Y
```

export data pump:

```
CONTENT=METADATA_ONLY
```